# Can someone on same wifi access my computer?

Tags: wifi, macos, remote-desktop

I was connected to a hotel wifi and airport wifi last week. Some of the files in my Downloads folder now has been compromised (soft keys stolen).

- Can someone connected to same wifi gain access to my Mac? at hotel or airports or home?
- - I never install unknown softwares/apps or grant access to any apps on my mac.
- Is there a way to know if anybody remotely accessed my computer between certain dates?

Comment: If you have any ports open on your device, and there are services accepting incoming connections running on these ports, then yes - other devices on your network can connect to these services on your device.  This is true regardless of whether you are on a wifi network, or a wired LAN.

Comment: "Is it possible?" Sure. How to tell if there was a remote connection? You need to look for the logs, if any, in the operating system. That's an easier question to answer, but it's not a security question.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but is very unlikely...
They need to be an experienced hacker...
I'd recommend that you stay away from public WI-FI...